# How to get sum of counts of name when one name apear more than one time in database

Tags: mysql

i have created database to enter monthly seed stock data of reservoirs. in that database has following columns id,reservoir_name, reservoir_code, stock-qty, stock_date. normally one reservoir receive seeds more than one time. then end of the year i wanted to count how many reservoirs i have stock seeds in this year.

so i try to use following SQL
`SELECT reservoir_code, COUNT(id) FROM reservoir_stocking WHERE stock_date BETWEEN '2022-01-01' AND '2022-12-31' GROUP BY reservoir_code`
to find how many reservoir i have stock seeds. it only give stock counts of reservoirs separately. then i try to combine with following query

`SELECT COUNT(id) FROM (SELECT COUNT(reservoir_code) AS count FROM reservoir_stocking GROUP BY reservoir_stocking HAVING count > 1) as A`

it only give error massages. please help to count no of reservoirs i have stock seeds this year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `COUNT(DISTINCT reservoir_code)` to count the distinct reservoir codes, ensuring that each reservoir is counted only once.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT reservoir_code) AS reservoir_count FROM reservoir_stocking WHERE stock_date BETWEEN '2022-01-01' AND '2022-12-31';
```

This query will give you the count of distinct reservoirs that received seeds in the year 2022.

Comment: Thank you very much,  it works as i expected.